# Set custom UITabBar font color under iOS7

Tags: uitabbar, ios7, uicolor

It seems that `[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];` is no longer working propertly under iOS7. I can set the background image, but the selected text is no longer getting the red color. I'm calling this from my application delegate. Has anyone tried to set the `UITabBar` font color and style under iOS7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is `tintColor` in iOS7, try the below:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

**Edit**:

To tint the non active buttons, put the below code in your VC's `viewDidLoad`:

```
[self.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"item_seleted.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"item_unselected.png"]];
```

Answer (score 4):

It worked for me..

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Answer (score 2):

To tint not active items I used this

```
UITabBarItem *item = [self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];

// here you need to use the icon with the color you want, as it will be rendered as it is
item.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselected.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

// this icon is used for selected tab and it will get tinted as defined in self.tabBar.tintColor
item.selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"];
```